# Creating Unique Compound Index where one field can be null in Mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I created  Unique Compound Index:

```
Alter Table TableX Add Unique Index `UniqueRecord` (A,B,C,D)
```

The issue is that sometimes `C` can be NULL.

I noticed that

```
`Insert IGNORE`
```

Was still in some cases adding duplicate records and this turned out to be when those incoming records had `C` as NULL.

I tested the hypothesis that this was an issue by doing:

```
Select concat(A,B,C,D) as Index from TableA where C is NULL
```

And `Index` in each of those cases was in fact NULL. Once I remove the null field from the select:

```
Select concat(A,B,D) as Index from TableA where C is NULL
```

I get the expected string values vs nulls.

So the question is, other than doing an update like `set C='' where C is NULL` is there some way to set up the Index so that it works? I am loathe to simply make the Index `A,B,D` as that might introduce unwanted dupes when `C` in fact is not NULL.

Update:
I did try using `IfNull` in the Index creation but Mysql did not like that:

```
Alter Table TableA Add Unique Index UniqueLocator (A,B,IfNull(C,''),D
```

Mysql said:

`[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'C,''),D)' at line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes MySQL allows NULLs in unique indexes, which is the right thing to do. But you can define column C as NOT NULL if you don't like that.

Comment: Tha is a pretty simple solution thanks. I'm still considering if that may introduce unexpected issues with existing code/queries.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL -- but not all databases -- allow duplicate `NULL` values in unique indexes.  I believe the ANSI standard is rather ambiguous on this point (or perhaps even contradictory).  You basically have two choices.

The first is to define a default value for the column.  This may not be appealing in terms of code, but it will at least generate an error on duplicate insert.  For instance, if "C" is a foreign key reference to an auto-incremented id, then you might use `-1` or `0` as the default value.  If it is a date, you might use the zero date.

The other solution is a trigger, where you manually check for the duplicate values before doing an insert (or update).

Comment: @GordongLinoff I did try to use IfNull in the index description i.e. `Alter Table TableA Add Unique Index UniqueLocator (A,B,IfNull(C,''),D)` but it did not like that. Right now I am altering the field to be Empty String vs NULL just trying to determine where that might break other code.

Comment: @user3649739 . . . One possibility is to use a special value and then access the table using a view that turns it back into a `NULL` value.

Comment: @Linoff Thanks, so far changing the field to Empty String as default vs NULL seems to have solved the issue.